# Very basic question on vector line integrals.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, vector-fields

I've to find the line integral

**$\int_{x=a}^{0} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{d l}$**

evaluated over a  line in the $x-y$ plane given as $y=1$ where $\vec{F}=\hat{\imath}$.

**My solution**:

> Since we are moving from $x=a$ to $x=0$ ,our length element should be $\vec{d l}=-d x \hat{i}$. The line integral is then :$\int_{a}^{0} \vec{F} \cdot d l=\int_{a}^{0} \hat{\imath} \cdot(-d x \hat{i})=-\int_{a}^{0} d x=a$. Which is incorrect.

What is incorrect in my approach?

Comment: The sign of $dl$ is wrong.

Comment: Isn't$d l$ pointing towards left ,so it should be negative?

Comment: No. It is pointing to the right. The actual direction is taken care by the integration limits. You are applying that correction twice.

Comment: Is it then that no matter the orientation of the curve, the length elements should be taken positive ?

Comment: The direction of length element is the direction of your coordinate axis. If $x$ is increasing to the right, $dl$ points to the right

Comment: Thank you Andrei, it fascinates me how the integral limits correct the line integral. I suppose it has to do with the Riemann sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that when you write $\vec{dl} = -dx\hat{i}$, you are already setting the orientation of the path, but the orientation is already included in your order of integration from $a$ to $0$, which says you are going backwards. So, you should use one of the following:
$$\int_{0}^{a}\hat{i}\cdot(-dx\hat{i}) \quad  \mbox{or} \quad \int_{a}^{0}\hat{i}\cdot dx\hat{i}$$

Note that there is another approach which is more rigorous and prevents thes sort of mistakes. You have $\vec{F}(\vec{r}) = (1,0)$ and the parametrized curve is $\gamma(t) = (t, 1)$, where $t$ goes from $a$ to $0$. Now, $\gamma'(t) = (1,0)$ and $F(\gamma(t))=(1,0)$, so:
$$\int_{C}\vec{F}(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec{l} = \int_{a}^{0}\vec{F}(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)dt = \int_{a}^{0}(1,0)\cdot (1,0)dt = \int_{a}^{0}dt = -a$$

Comment: Is it then that no matter the orientation of the curve, the length elements should be taken positive ?

Comment: Yes. The procedure of taking $d\vec{l} = -dx\hat{i}$ already embodies the orientation. This is the way physicists usually do, but when physicists do it they usually don't care about the extremes $a$ an $b$ of the integral, they just perform some sort of indefinite integral to prove some known formula. But when an actuall calculation is demanded, you have to be careful because these signs change the result.

Comment: Thank you. So in any general case the length elements should be taken positive and then the integral limits will take care? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it sounds about right!